# Spring Property not recognised on HTTPS Connector

Tags: mule

I am trying to create an HTTPS connector in Mule so that I can call an HTTPS endpoint as part of a flow. However when I try to add the `sslType` spring property, I get an error.

I have an HTTPS connector defined as so:

```
<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
        xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
        xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
        xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
        xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
        xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper"
        xmlns:domain="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain/current/mule-domain-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">

...

        <https:connector name="HTTPSConnector" doc:name="HTTPS-Connector"
                cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0"
                clientSoTimeout="${service.timeout}" serverSoTimeout="60000" socketSoLinger="0">

                <spring:property name="sslType" value="TLSv1.2" />
        </https:connector>

...
```

Mule is throwing the error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'spring:property'. 
One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":service-overrides, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https":tls-client, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https":tls-key-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https":tls-server, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https":tls-protocol-handler}' is expected.
```

What changes do I need to get this property recognised?

Comment: Which version of mule are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without issues for me running in 3.5.2, if that is the version you are using. Maybe there is something else in the omitted snippets? If there other configurations inside the `<https:connector>` element that are not shown in the snippet shared then ensure that `spring:property is the first one.

Note that even if it works you might be finding some other issues related to the SSL engine and Java SSL support to make it work with TLS 1.2. For example 3.5.2 only supports Java 7. You might find some bug, mentioned at https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Setting-the-TLS-version-for-the-legacy-HTTPS-connector. Both Mule 3.5 and Java 7 are at end of life.

If you are using a current Mule 3 version, Mule 3.9.5 is recommended as the latest and greatest at this time, then TLS 1.2 support is the default. Same with Mule 4.x. Having said that, the legacy HTTP connector you are using has been deprecated for several years, and the new HTTP Listener/HTTP Requester that replace it are recommended.

Comment: Thanks @aled I must have had a nonprintable character or something in there. Deleted the file and recreated it exactly as is and the issue went away! Very strange